# Error Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 in angular2

Tags: angular, http-status-code-405

I enabled cross origin but still shown the error :

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://local.admin.com/public/api/v1/employee/20. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Comment: A 405 means method not allowed. Is this a POST, PUT or GET method? The server needs to allow the method that is being used. In any case, use the browser dev tools to see the network traffic to get more detail on what might be wrong.

Comment: I got the the error in put,delete and post method

Comment: if i used get method then error not come

Comment: OK. On the server you'll need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header so it allows those methods for CORS. See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: already added at server side

Comment: OK. We probably can't help more unless you can show both the request and response headers. Use the browser dev tools to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error in lumen api so I have add header in lumen now problem is solved

Comment: can you specify which header ? @krunal

Comment: palanik\lumen\Middleware\LumenCors use this